# RxJs of operator for Observable<void>

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have a function that returns `Observable<void>` and I need it to return an observable that immediately emits and completes. Normally I would use the `of` operator to do this, but it doesn't work with `void`.

Things I've tried that don't work:

```
return of(); // doesn't emit
```

```
return of({}); // TypeScript compilation error 'Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<void>'.'
```

Things I've tried that do work, but I don't like:

```
return of({}).map(() => {}); // does extra work just to avoid compiler error
```

```
return of({}) as unknown as Observable<void>; // yucky casting
```

```
return new Observable<void>(s => {s.next(); s.complete();}); // verbose
```

I'm currently using the last one since it works without doing extra work, but I'd prefer a shortcut like `of`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return `of(void 0)`.

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-yn6dmr

Comment: This seems like the best option for clarity.

Answer (score 4):

Short and simple: [`of(null)`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yd1ymn?file=index.ts) or [`of(undefined)`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yd1ymn?file=index.ts).

Comment: `of(null)` causes a compiler error. `of(undefined)` does work.

Comment: of(null) works for me. What compiler error do you get?

Comment: `Type 'Observable<null>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<void>'`

Answer (score 1):

You can set generic type for operator `of`:

```
return of<void>(undefined);
```

or if you won't, do IIFE, like this way:

```
return of(((): void => {})());
```

Comment: Personally, I don't think the second one passes the "verbose" test. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also return `EMPTY`:

```
import { EMPTY, Observable } from "rxjs";

function test(): Observable<void> {
  return EMPTY
}

test().subscribe(e => console.log("sub"))
```

Comment: `EMPTY` doesn't work because it either doesn't emit or doesn't complete. As a little context, I'm using this for an Angular resolver, which appears to require both emit and complete to work.